# Resources for learning Category Theory from the perspective of logic

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation

I took a glance at some freely available online scripts of Category Theory, but I suspect I would get stuck quickly, as many examples presuppose some knowledge of Algebra which I don't have. I'm mainly interested in Category Theory because of its foundational role in logic, so I think that a book/script written from that standpoint would be beneficial for me. I would especially appreciate if the material was free, as I'm not very rich. (Though this shouldn't discourage you to also recommend non-free resources.)

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Do you already know some category theory, or are you looking for a text that will teach the very basics of category theory from a logical perspective?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I know exactly nothing about Category Theory. I got interested in it because I heard it's deeply connected to logic, and logic is my love. $\heartsuit$

Answer (score 8):

I recently bought Goldblatt, TOPOI, The Categorical Analysis of Logic, Dover publications.

It might interest you. I got it through Amazon.

Comment: Dover publications are Great! I love their philosophy

Comment: Have you read it and can vouch for its quality?

Comment: @Godbless: It's excellent (at least as far as I've read). And you can check this for yourself, since it's available for free: https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/books-by-independent-authors/Topoi-The-Categorial-Analysis-of-Logic/toc/bia/1403013939

Comment: +1 for Golblatt Topoi. You will like it.